# How would I create this query using only joins and no sub query?

Tags: mysql

As the title suggests, what is the way to re-write this to have the exclusion solely as joins?

```
select users.id from users where id not in ("select
pu.owner_id from projects p
inner join
projects_users pu on
pu.owned_project_id = p.id
where p.project_name = 'This is an example of a project'")
```

I thought this might work, but it's not returning anything from users that doesn't exist in project_users:

```
select u.id from users u
        left outer join projects_users pu on
        pu.owner_id = u.id
        inner join projects p on
        pu.owned_project_id = p.id          
        where NOT p.project_name = 'This is an example of a project'
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT    a.id
FROM      users a
LEFT JOIN project_users b ON a.id = b.owner_id
LEFT JOIN projects c ON b.owned_project_id = c.id AND 
          c.project_name = 'This is an example of a project'
WHERE     c.id IS NULL
```